# Anime where children go to a school to learn to fight with powers they get from orbs

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

I saw this a long time ago so the details are vague, I apologise. I remember just a specific scene.

A bunch of children are being trained  to use their powers and then, I think, when the training session is over the character goes to their room by elevator and flops on his bed or something. I kind of remember that the kids got their powers from small orbs or marks on their foreheads.

This is something I saw on TV by the way. As I remember, the art style wasn't very heavy, rather on the light side. It didn't look very dark and depressing either but kind of gave *Pokemon* vibes, like winning a competition or mastering that magic was the end game.

Any and all answers are appreciated so thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, can you describe the appearance of any of the characters, such as hair colour/style?